# Upload a image from react to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: react-hooks, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to upload a image from react hooks to ASP.NET Core Web API. So far I can upload image in react but when I send the image to the server I get null.

This is the client side code:

Presentation:

```
<DropzoneArea
acceptedFiles={['image/*']}
onChange={onChange}
showFileNames
dropzoneText="Drag And Drop / Upload Identity Card Photo Here "
showAlerts={false}
filesLimit={1}
/>
```

Logic:

```
const [personPhoto, setPersonPhoto] = useState([]);
 const onChange = (e) => { 
        setPersonPhoto(e)
    }
const submitForm = () => {
        let form = new FormData();    
        for(var i = 0; i<personPhoto.length; i++)
            form.append('image', personPhoto[i]);
        console.log(form);   
        CandidatePost(form).then( result => {
            setMessage(result.message);
            if(result.messageType === MessageType.info)
                setMessageType(MessageType.infoFormat);
            else
                setMessageType(MessageType.errorFormat);    
        })
        .catch(error => {
            setMessage(error.message);
            setMessageType(MessageType.errorFormat);
        });
    }
```

Request:

```
const CandidatePost = async (form) => { 
  return await Post(form, CANDIDATES_API_URL);
}

const Post = async (item, url) =>{     
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  var requestOptions = 
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,             
      redirect: 'follow',
      body: JSON.stringify(item)
    };
    return await fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(response =>{return response.json(); })
      .then(result => {return result; })
      .catch(err => {return err; });    
}
```

Server-side code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostImage([FromForm] IFormFile Image)
{
    // here I must do operation with my image but is always null
    srvImage.SaveImage(image);
}
```

What do I need to do to send my image to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I send the image to the server I get null

It seems that you'd like to upload image file via form data, to achieve it, please modify your code to remove `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` Header that you set and provide formdata (`item`) to the body of the request, like below.

```
const Post = async (item, url) =>{     
  var requestOptions = 
    {
      method: 'POST',          
      redirect: 'follow',
      body: item
    };
    return await fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(response =>{return response.json(); })
      .then(result => {return result; })
      .catch(err => {return err; });    
}
```

Test Result

*Form with inputs*

[image]

*Get uploaded image file*

[image]